# Modifying horizontal axis of a PDF plot

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms

I have a bunch of particles that I can measure their volume.
PDFs of the size distribution by volume of particles, v(a),  measured are reasonably well represented by lognormal distributions of the form
[image]

```
ag = 6.;
Sigma = 1.;(*Assign a value to Sigma*)dist = 
 ProbabilityDistribution[
  1/(a Sigma Sqrt[2 Pi]) Exp[-((Log[a] - Log[ag])^2/(2 Sigma^2))], {a,
    0.001, Infinity} (*Make sure a doesn't start from 0*)];

va = RandomVariate[dist, 10000];

Show[Histogram[va, 200, "ProbabilityDensity"], 
 Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0.001, 50}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> All] (*Use Red as PlotStyle*)]
```

How, I can have the PDF by volume on the vertical axis and particle size on the horizontal axis? One way is to change the horizontal ticks, but is there any other way?

Comment: [`LogNormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogNormalDistribution.html) is built-in, just use `dist = LogNormalDistribution[Log[ag], Sigma];` And, `PDF[dist, 0]` evaluates to `0`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description correct, you want to plot the inverse of the PDF. The problem here is, that the inverse is a multivalued function, therefore we can not use "FunctionInverse".

To solve this problem, we first determine the argument: x0 of the maximum of the PDF:

```
ag = 6.;
Sigma = 1.
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
   1/(a Sigma Sqrt[
        2 Pi]) Exp[-((Log[a] - Log[ag])^2/(2 Sigma^2))], {a, 0.001, 
    Infinity}];
pdf[x_] := PDF[dist, x];
x0=x /. FindRoot[pdf'[x] == 0, {x, 2}];
```

Then we calculate the inverse as the two y values belonging to a given x (note: Reduce gives a message that it rationalize the arguments):

```
inv[x_] := (t = Reduce[{PDF[dist, a] == x}, a]; {t[[1, 2]], t[[2, 2]]});
```

Now we can plot the multivalued inverse:

```
Plot[inv[x], {x, 0, PDF[dist, x0]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Histogram` with the option `BarOrigin -> Left` and use `ParametricPlot` for graphing the `PDF`:

```
Show[Histogram[va, 200, "ProbabilityDensity", BarOrigin -> Left], 
 ParametricPlot[{PDF[dist, x], x}, {x, 0.001, 50}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, post-process the output from `Plot[PDF[..]...]` to reverse the line coordinates and use it as `Epilog`:

```
Histogram[va, 200, "ProbabilityDensity", BarOrigin -> Left, 
 Epilog -> First[Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0.001, 50}, PlotStyle -> Red] /. 
    Line[x_] :> Line[Reverse /@ x]]]
```

[image]